# How to package and deploy AWS python lambda functions automatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, git, aws-lambda, deployment

I have created a AWS python lambda using some modules like **kafka**, **numpy**, **boto3** etc.

**Boto3** is already provided by AWS environment. For **Numpy**, I am using AWS predefined layer.

After deploying it as `.zip` file with kafka and other modules, the size is around `14 MB` and AWS UI wont show the code saying

> The deployment package of your Lambda function "ABC" is too large to enable inline code editing. However, you can still invoke your function.

The process I follow whenever I am making any change is -

1. Import any new module needed
2. pip install that module to the existing directory where .py resides
3. Zip the directory
4. Upload the zip to S3
5. Point the Lambda to use this latest zip file from S3

I see this process is tedious and there should exist an easier and better way, so that other developers should also be able to contribute the enhancements easily.

I am also trying to understand how to commit this to git, is it just the `.py` file that I need to commit, if yes then should I also commit `requirements.txt` so that others can easily start testing in their environments ?

Do I need to create any pipeline to make the whole process automated and much more developer friendly for local testing ?

Are there any tools that make this process more simpler? Please guide.

Comment: you can create layer for the library to reduce the code size, or you can use code build to deploy your lambda each time with changes.

Answer (score 0):

For the git piece: I'd recommend just checking in your main python file and a related set of requirements.txt files.

The two paths that I've used for easier Lambda deployments are Serverless and Terraform. I'll outline them briefly (there's also Amazon's CDK but I am less familiar with it).

- Serverless is basically a wrapper around Amazon's Infrastructure as Code tool (CloudFormation); either a set of JSON or YAML that define your Lambda and any associated resources. [Here's a decent example of your setup](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/v3/aws-python-telegram-bot/serverless.yml) i.e. a git tracked `handler.py`, a `requirements.txt` file and a `serverless.yml` to deploy the lambda.
- For Terraform, it's a more general purpose Infrastructure as Code tool that has plugins for each major cloud provider. The best example I could dig up was a [simplified repo](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/master/examples/simple/main.tf)

Terraform's main advantage is for change tracking in a more generic way, but Serverless I think is simpler if you're not familiar with either one. (Serverless uses CloudFormation stacks for tracking changes, which are a bit funkier than Terraform's state management).

Most ideally; you'd want to have these things run in a pipeline on merge, so that your lamda is updated with new code changes after a code review and merge into a git repo. It might look like:

1. Someone submits a Pull Request to your Git repository
2. The request is reviewed/ merged
3. On before/merge, some tests run to verify the code
4. You run the serverless/terraform deploy to update the lambda
5. Do some final, end to end verification on the new deployment

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything!